# Является ли код рекурсивным?

Tags: python, рекурсия

Я изучаю рекурсию и решил написать свою, для нахождения наибольшего числа в массиве.

```
def high(list, max):

    if list == []:

        return max

    elif list[0] > max:

        max = list[0]

    return high(list[1:], max)

list = [1,2,3,4,510,6]

high(list, 0)
```

Здесь я взял простой пример, но при многих других он тоже работает.
У меня по этому коду есть два вопроса:

1. Является ли это рекурсией вообще?
2. Корректно ли написана данная рекурсия?

Comment: Да, рекурсия, да, корректно

Comment: Если в массиве будут только отрицательные числа, то выходе вы получите 0, что не является верным ответом.

Comment: @ЮрийКозлов можно вместо 0 написать float('-inf') и всё будет корректно

Comment: Если подходить строго - то претензия есть. Нужно угадать со значением `max` при начальном вызове, что не есть хорошо. Нужно сделать параметр `max` опциональным, и? если он не определён, безусловно присваивать ему `list[0]`. Это даст возможность получить чуть более универсальную функцию - т.е. не просто вернуть максимальное, но и максимальное не менее заданного.

Comment: @andreymal Собственно, Akina уже сказал все, что я хотел оставить автору на подумать.

Comment: В идеале - на вход функции вообще не должно подаваться значение максимума. На входе должен быть только проверяемый массив, а максимум возвращается как итог ее работы.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я бы сделал по-другому:

- На вход подается только список, а не список и число.
- Сначала обрабатываем тривиальные случаи (база рекурсии) - когда список пустой и когда в нем один элемент. Когда список пустой пусть возвращается `None`. Когда в списке один элемент - очевидно он и является максимальным.
- Если в списке более одного элемента, то сравниваем первый элемент и рекурсивно максимум из оставшихся элементов, и возвращаем большее из значений.

```
def my_max(s):
    if not s:
        return None
    elif len(s) == 1:
        return s[0]
    else:
        # return max(s[0], my_max(s[1:])
        x = my_max(s[1:])
        if s[0] > x:
            return s[0]
        else:
            return x
```

Чтобы не резать список (при сечении списка каждый раз создается новый объект списка, а это лишние накладные расходы на память и копирование списка), можно вторым параметром передавать индекс текущего ("начального") элемента, в остальном алгоритм остается тем же:

```
def my_max(s, i=0):
    if i >= len(s):
        return None
    elif i == len(s)-1:
        return s[i]
    else:
        x = my_max(s, i+1)
        if s[i] > x:
            return s[i]
        else:
            return x
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Да, это рекурсия.
2. Написано плохо. Если на вход подать пустой список, то результатом станет параметр `max`, что очевидно не является верным. Если же в списке не окажется ни одного числа больше, чем `max`, то результатом опять окажется `max`, что тоже неверно. Во-вторых, не стоит использовать слово `list` в качестве имени переменной, потому что это имя встроенной функции.

Comment: «что очевидно не является верным» — неочевидно, такое поведение вполне может быть специально задумано автором этой функции

Comment: @andreymal может. Но в условиях про это не сказано, значит, не задумано.